# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' and matplotlib is already installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, modulenotfounderror

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I am trying to use matplotlib in Python. I am getting the above error.

matplotlib is installed and upgraded I have double checked it on my command prompt.

I have made sure that matplotlib is installed and I have updated it:
These are the things I have tried on my command prompt
{pip install matplotlib, pip3 install matplotlib} --- and it was stated that the requirements are already satisfied.
I have also tried {python -m pip install --upgrade pip} and version matplotlib- 3.6.3 was successfully installed.

I then restarted my visual studio code, but I am still getting the same error. What should I do?

Comment: You may have installed it for a different version of Python or in a virtual environment.

Comment: The version of Python I am using is 3.8.5 and I have upgraded to matplotlib-3.6.3 and I installed matplotlib using "pip3 install matplotlib"

Comment: Check if "pip3 --version" shows the expected Python version.

Comment: yes, they re both 3.8

Comment: ① What is your OS? ② if you start Python from the command line and at the REPL you type `import matplotlib`, what happens? ③ if `import matplotlib` doesn't raise an error, type `import sys; sys.path`, then **from Visual Studio** do the same, i.e., `import sys; sys.path` and eventually compare the two lists of directories that you have obtained ④ please [edit] your Q to reflect all your findings.

Comment: Thank you! There were 2 Python version that Visual Studio was using. So I had to clear all the environment and did the set up from scratch